After Ubuntu Studio upgrade to 24.04 Onboard onscreen keyboard not working for authentication
I upgraded Ubuntu studio on my son's computer to 24.04. Since then the Onboard onscreen keyboard is not detected (doesn't work) for authentication. I had similar problem some time ago, and I know there is a relatively simple solution, but I just can't remember and all my search on the net turned out useless.
Can anybody help me?
